# Updating the content of a code behind generated button

Tags: c#, wpf

How do i do that - Updating the content of a code behind generated button

```
  void MakeButtonQ()
    {
        Button b2 = new Button();
        b2.Content = Class1.Question;
        b2.Height = 150;
        b2.Width = 230;
        b2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        b2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(b2);
    }
```

I will have to update the content using code behind. Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Jonathan

Comment: I assume you are working with WPF?

Comment: Do you have specific values for specific buttons in that StackPanel? Does every button have a particular related class?

Comment: Yes, each has specific value to be changed to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a reference to the button in a variable and change the content using this variable.

```
Button myButton;

void MakeButtonQ() 
{ 
    Button b2 = new Button(); 
    b2.Content = Class1.Question; 
    b2.Height = 150; 
    b2.Width = 230; 
    b2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White); 
    b2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black); 
    stackPanel1.Children.Add(b2); 

    myButton = b2
} 

void ChangeButtonsContent()
{
    myButton.Content = "Content changed";
}
```

Comment: HMm i cant because even if i give it a name lets same button2.name = "test" and type
test.content = SavedReference;

The error would be at test because there is no such button?

Comment: I added some example code. Using a variable is more convenient, because you don't loose type information. Of course, you can also save an array or list.

Comment: Thanks for your help, just to check so by doing this myButton = b2, it actually creates a reference to access the "Created button"

Comment: Well, kind of. b2 itself is a reference to the created button. With `myButton = b2` you copy the reference to myButton for further access. But in general, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the code-behind is a futile effort that will cause continual stress. Thankfully there is an alternative!

The code-behind class is a partial class so it will have a matching file you can edit without the .designer part of the filename. In there add a method that uses Controls.FindControl to access the generated button and then set the additional/alternative properties you want and call that from the constructor after the form initialization has happened.